# Pagination issues in py-substrate-interface

Tags: python, substrateinterface

It is not clear how to use pagination in py-substrate-interface.  In the sample code below, there are only 32 records so all the query should be complete, but `result.loading_complete` shows `false`.

```
from substrateinterface import SubstrateInterface

url = 'wss://shiden.api.onfinality.io/public-ws'
substrate = SubstrateInterface(url)

result = substrate.query_map('Contracts', 'CodeStorage', block_hash = None, page_size = 100, ignore_decoding_errors = True)
start_key = result.last_key
print(f"loading complete {result.loading_complete} | size {len(result.records)} | next start key {start_key}")
```

When I do want to query the next page, I am running the same query_map call with the added `start_key` parameter.  Is that correct, because there is also a `retrieve_next_page` call in the result object, but I can't figure out how to use it.

```
result = substrate.query_map('Contracts', 'CodeStorage', block_hash = None, page_size = 100, start_key = start_key, ignore_decoding_errors = True)
```

Here are the relevant components of the `results` object:
..., 'block_hash', 'current_index', 'ignore_decoding_errors', 'last_key', '**loading_complete**', 'max_results', 'module', 'page_size', 'params', 'records', '**retrieve_next_page**', 'storage_function', 'substrate']

So unless I am misunderstanding something, `loading_complete` is not correctly reporting when it is done and `retrieve_next_page` doesn't seem to do what it implies.  Also, the documentation could be improved by adding some examples, especially one that includes pagination.  Nonetheless, py-substrate-interface is a very handy tool.

Comment: The documentation has been revamped, so hopefully that will make the usage more clear: https://polkascan.github.io/py-substrate-interface/usage/#query-a-mapped-storage-function

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to handle `query_map` is use it as an iterator instead of manual last-key tracking.
For example all accounts of `System::Account` for Kusama:

```python
from substrateinterface import SubstrateInterface

substrate = SubstrateInterface(
    url="wss://kusama-rpc.polkadot.io",
)

query = substrate.query_map('System', 'Account', page_size=1000)

for (i, (account, account_info)) in enumerate(query):
    print(f"#{i} '{account.value}': {account_info.value['data']['free']}")
```

You can play around with the page size and see that it prints way more than 1000 accounts.